# Is there a better way to write this IF statment?

Tags: php, if-statement

```
if($colour && 
      ((strlen($colour) == 7 && preg_match("/#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}/",$colour)) ||
       (strlen($colour) == 4 && preg_match("/#[0-9a-fA-F]{3}/",$colour)))) {
```

- If $colour has a value **AND**

  - $colour is a 7 digit string and conforms to the 7 digit hex colour format **OR**
  - $colour is a 4 digit string and conforms to the 4 digit hex colour format

(String lengths include `hash`, hence 3 & 6 become 4 & 7)

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: *(tip)* http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/decompose-conditional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are. If you use RegEx, you can just as well use one regex, like this. The length can be skipped too, by using start or string/end of string *anchors*.

```
if ($colour && preg_match("/^#([0-9a-fA-F]){3}(([0-9a-fA-F]){3})?$/", $colour)
{
}
```

I think the 'check for value' can be skipped to, but that might make sense as an optimization.

[edit]

It turns out to be an example on the [RegEx cheat sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/).

Answer (score 1):

Let your regular expressions check the length of the string by adding the ^ and $ signs signaling start/end of a string, and combining your regular expressions:

```
if (preg_match("/^#[0-9a-fA-F]{3}|#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}$/", $colour)) {
```

Comment: i think $colour is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (preg_match("/^#([0-9a-f]{3}){1,2}$/i", $colour)) {
```

seems enough to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could anchor your regex with `^` and `$` so the length is implied.

```
if( $colour && 
    (  preg_match("/^#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}$/",$colour)
    || preg_match("/^#[0-9a-fA-F]{3}$/",$colour)
  ) ) {
```

I don't know php that well, but in perl you would need to escape the `$` as `\$` or use single quotes instead.

Answer (score -1):

Your regexp already specify stings' lenghts so you do not need to check it if you set start `^` and end `$` boundaries:

```
if ( preg_match("/^#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}$/", $colour) || preg_match("/^#[0-9a-fA-F]{3}$/",$colour) ) {}
```

Comment: I think you should replace `&&` by `||`